# If every real subseries whose set of indices has natural density zero converges, does the original series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, convergence-divergence

> Proposition: Suppose $a_n\in\mathbb{R}\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in A} a_n $
> converges for *every* $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ with zero
> [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Definition). Then does $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
>  a_n $ necessarily converge?

I can neither think of a counter-example, nor a method to prove it.

If we relax/weaken the "with zero natural density" condition, to "with at most non-negative natural density ($\alpha>0$)". Then it is easy to show the result is true. Just choose $N> \frac{1}{\alpha}.$ For each $m\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ define $X_m:= \{ kN + m: k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \}.$ Then $\mathbb{N} = \displaystyle\bigcup_{m\in\{1,\ldots,N\}} X_m.\ $ For each $m\in\{1,\ldots,N\},\ \displaystyle\sum_{k\in X_m} a_{k}$ converges, and it is not difficult to then show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{n\in X_0} a_n + \sum_{n\in X_1} + \ldots + \sum_{n\in X_{n-1}} a_n,\ $ which converges.

Comment: Note: I changed the question, because the original one had a trivial counter-example.

Comment: For series $\sum\frac{1}{n}$, can we construct a density zero set $A$ so that $\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges?  Perhaps we can imitate this proof for the general problem stated.

Comment: @GEdgar Why, that's easy: primes will do.

Comment: @GEdgar - so you are thinking about the contrapositive. I think that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma: If a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is such that $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ diverges, then there exists $\varepsilon>0\ $ and a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}},$ such that $\ n_{k} - n_{k-1} \geq \frac{k}{2}\ $ and either $\ x_{n_{2k}} - x_{n_{2k-1}} > \varepsilon\quad $ or $\ x_{n_{2k}} - x_{n_{2k-1}} < -\varepsilon\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Proof: Since $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ diverges, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy, that is, $\ \exists\ \varepsilon > 0\ $ such that for all $i\in\mathbb{N},\ \exists\ n>m>i\ $ such that   $\ \left\lvert x_{n} - x_{m} \right\rvert > \varepsilon.\ $ Define $\ m_0:=0.\ $ For each $\ k\geq 1,\ $ the following is true. $\ \exists\ b > a > m_{2(k-1)}+k\ $ such that $\ \left\lvert x_{b} - x_{a} \right\rvert > \varepsilon.\ $ Furthermore, $\ \exists\ d > c > b+k\ $ such that $\ \left\lvert x_{d} - x_{c} \right\rvert > \varepsilon.\ $ It can be shown that there is $\ m_{2k-1}\in \{a,b\}\ $ and $\ m_{2k}\in \{c,d\}\ $ such that $\ \left\lvert x_{ m_{2k} } - x_{ m_{2k-1} } \right\rvert > \varepsilon.\ $ Now note that $\ m_{2k} - m_{2k-1} \geq k\ $ and $\ m_{2k-1} - m_{2(k-1)} \geq k,\ $ so that $\ m_k - m_{k-1} \geq \frac{k}{2}.$

This gives us a sequence of natural numbers, $\ \left\{ m_k \right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} $ such that  $\ \left\lvert x_{ m_{2k} } - x_{ m_{2k-1} } \right\rvert >\varepsilon\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.$ We must have either $\ x_{ m_{2k} } - x_{ m_{2k-1} } >\varepsilon\quad $ or $x_{ m_{2k} } - x_{ m_{2k-1} } < -\varepsilon\ $ for infinitely many $\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ Let $\ (j_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ be a subsequence of $ \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that either $\ x_{ m_{2j_k} } - x_{ m_{2j_k-1} } >\varepsilon\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}\ $ or $\ x_{ m_{2j_k} } - x_{ m_{2j_k-1} } < -\varepsilon\ \quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ Now let $\ n_{2k} =  m_{2j_k}\ $ and $\ n_{2k-1} =  m_{2j_k-1}\ $ for each $\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $

This sequence $\ (n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ satisfies the conditions in the Lemma, so we are done.

$$$$

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n\ $ diverges. I show that there exists $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ with zero natural density such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in A} a_n $ diverges. This would prove the contrapositive of the proposition and therefore the proposition itself.

Let $b_k:=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k a_n.\ $ Since $\ \displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k\ $ diverges, from the lemma there exists $\varepsilon>0\ $ and a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}},$ such that $\ n_{k} - n_{k-1} \geq \frac{k}{2}\ $ and either $\ b_{n_{2k}} - b_{n_{2k-1}} > \varepsilon \ $ or  $\ b_{n_{2k}} - b_{n_{2k-1}}  < -\varepsilon \ $ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ Suppose the former is true (the proof is very similar if we instead suppose the latter). That is, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n_{2k-1}+1}^{n_{2k}} a_i > \varepsilon\ $ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $

For each $k\in\mathbb{N},\ $ consider the set of consecutive integers $\ S^k:= \{ n_{2k-1}+1,\ n_{2k-1}+2,\ \ldots,\ n_{2k}-1,\ n_{2k}\}.\ $ Note that, since $\ (n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ is strictly increasing, $n_{2(k-1)}< n_{2k-1},\ $ and so, $\ k_1 \neq k_2 \implies \ S^{k_1} \cap S^{k_2} = \emptyset.\ $ For each $\ j\in \{1,2,\ldots, k\},\ $ define $S_j:= \{ n_{2k-1}+j + ik: i\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \} \cap S.$ Since $\ \left\lvert S^k \right\rvert = n_{2k} - n_{2k-1} \geq k,\ $ the sets $\ S_j\ $ partition $S^k$ into exactly $\ k\ $ nonempty sets, with the distance between any two members of $\ S_j\ $ being $\geq k.$

If $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in S_j} a_n \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{k}\ \forall\ j\in \{1,2,\ldots, k\},\ $ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in S^k} a_n \leq k\frac{\varepsilon}{k} = \varepsilon,\ $ which is false, a contradiction.

Therefore, $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i\in S_j} a_i > \frac{\varepsilon}{k}\ $ for some $\ j\in \{1,2,\ldots, k\}.\ $ For a given $k\in\mathbb{N},$ let one such $j$ be called $j_k,\ $ so that we reall have $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in S_{j_k}} a_n > \frac{\varepsilon}{k}.\ $

Let $\ A = \displaystyle\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} S_{j_k}. $

We see that,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n\in A} a_n > \varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} $ diverges.

Finally, let $\ A_N:= \left\lvert A\cap\{1,2,\ldots,N \}\right\rvert,\ $ and let $\ \alpha>0.\ $ Choose $\ k > \frac{1}{\alpha},\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ The distance between consecutive integer members of the set $\ S_{j_k}\ $ is $\ \geq k.\ $ Moreover, $\ \exists\ T\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that the distance between consecutive integer members of the $\ T-$th term and later of $\ A \ $ is $\ \geq k.\ $ To guarantee this, just choose the $\ T-$th term to be in $\ S_{j_k}\ $ or after. There exists $\ U\geq T\ $ such that, $\ \frac{A_N}{N} < \frac{1}{k} < \alpha \ \forall\ N\geq U.\ $ Since $\ \alpha\ $ was arbitrary, by the Sandwich theorem, $\ \displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{A_N}{N} = 0,\ $ and we are done.

Comment: I'm sure this can be made more succinct, whilst being kept formal.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that under the OP hypothesis, we have $\sum |a_n| < \infty$, so the series converges absolutely, hence it converges.

Assume $\sum |a_n|=\infty$ and wlog taking the subsequence of either positive or negative $a_n$ and changing sign in the second case, that $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n =\infty$, so there is $N_k, M_k \to \infty, M_k \ge 2N_k$ st $\sum_{N_k \le n \le M_k} a_n \ge 1$ for all $k \ge1$. In particular we can choose a subsequence $N_{k_m} \ge M_{k_m-1}^2$ and renumber $N_{k_m}=N_m, M_{k_m}=M_m$ so we can assume $N_k \ge M_{k-1}^2$

Splitting $[N_k, M_k]$ in $[\log k]+1$ subsets modulo $[\log k]+1$, so we put $N_k+a, N_k+a+([\log k]+1) ...N_k+a+m([\log k]+1)...$ in a given subset $I_{a,k}$ for each $a=0,..[\log k]$, there is at least one subset $I_k$ of length at most $(M_k-N_k+1)/([\log k]+1) \le M_k/\log k$ for which $\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n \ge 1/([\log k]+1)$

Clearly $I=\cup_{k}I_k$ is a disjoint union and $\sum_{n \in I}a_n =\sum_k \sum_{n \in I_k}a_n =\infty$

However if we fix $N$ there is a $k=k_N$ st either $M_k \le N < N_{k+1}$ or $N_k \le N <M_k$ and let $J_N=I \cap [1,N]$

$J_N \subset I_1 \cup ...I_k$ so the size of $J_N$ is at most the size of $I_k \cap [1,N]$ plus the size of $I_1 ..\cup I_{k-1}$ which have size at most $M_{k-1}$ since they are included in the segment $[1,M_{k-1}]$. But $N \ge N_k$ in both cases and $M_{k-1}/N_k \le 1/M_{k-1} \to 0$ so the part of $J_N$ inside $I_1 ..\cup I_{k-1}$ is negilgible wr $N$ so we just need to look at $|J_N \cap I_k|/N$; but from our choice of splitting we have that $I_k$ contains at most $N/([\log k]+1)$ numbers in $[1,N]$ for any $N$ since it contains just the numbers with a given residue $a$ modulo $[\log k]+1$, hence $|J_N \cap I_k|/N \le 1/\log k$.

Since $N \to \infty$ means $k_N \to \infty$ it follows $|J_N|/N \to 0, N \to \infty$ so $I$ has zero density but $\sum _{n \in I}a_n =\infty$ contradicting the hypothesis and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more informal sketch based on Adam Rubinson's answer.

Suppose $\sum a_n$ does not converge. The sequence of partial sums either diverges (WLOG to $+\infty$) or oscillates (infinitely often above and below some nontrivial interval), so we can find an $\epsilon>0$ and an infinite sequence of non-overlapping contiguous blocks of $(a_n)$ so that each block's sum is $>\epsilon$. We can choose these blocks to be arbitrarily large, so take the $k$th block to have length $l_k\ge k$.

Now partition the $k$th block into $k$ subsequences of approximately equal size (at most $\lceil\frac{l_k}k\rceil$) and let $A_k$ be one such subsequence with sum $>\epsilon/k$ (which must exist since the block sum is $>\epsilon$). Each $A_k$ has density $\frac{\lceil l_k/k\rceil}{l_k}\le\frac2k$ in its block, so $\bigcup_kA_k$ is a subsequence with natural density zero and divergent sum $\sum_k\frac\epsilon k$.